# MAAS 2.0 add subnet

Tags: maas

When I try to add a subnet on MAAS 2.0 I have the following configuration:

- VLAN masstest/untagged    space masstest
- CIDR 10.20.0.3/16         name testadmin
- Gateway IP 10.20.0.2      DNS 10.20.0.3

When I submit it I get "Extra data: line 1 column 6 (char 5)".
What is this trying to tell me?

Comment: CLI or GUI?  Either way, provide CLI text, or screenshots.  With your current question, there's no way to say anything is wrong.

Comment: From the web gui, I attempted to add a subnet, entered the above information in the web form and tried to submit it.  The error message doesn't tell me anything about what might be wrong with it.

Comment: I've duplicated this issue. :(

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is based on the text. Maybe a screenshot would help? Also, check `/var/log/maas/regiond.log` and search for a related `Traceback`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding an IP or a subnet? If you are adding a subnet you probably want it to be 10.20.0.0/16 since that is the network for the /16 and not 10.20.0.3/16.